# My program, works but keeps on returning 0

Tags: c++

Write a grading program for a class with the following grading policies:
a. There are two quizzes, each graded on the basis of 10 points.
b. There is one midterm exam and one final exam, each graded on the basis of
100 points.
c. The final exam counts for 50% of the grade, the midterm counts for 25%, and
the two quizzes together count for a total of 25%. (Do not forget to normalize
the quiz scores. They should be converted to a percentage before they are averaged
in.)
Any grade of 90 or more is an A, any grade of 80 or more (but less than 90) is a
B, any grade of 70 or more (but less than 80) is a C, any grade of 60 or more (but
less than 70) is a D, and any grade below 60 is an F. The program will read in the
student’s scores and output the student’s record, which consists of two quiz and
two exam scores as well as the student’s average numeric score for the entire course
and final letter grade. Define and use a structure for the student record.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct Report {

public:

};

int inputQuizzone ( int& Quizz1); //input functions take read in the input

int inputQuizztwo ( int& Quizz2); // user inputs result of quizz. Each quizz 
                                  // is 10 points     
int  inputMideterm ( int& MidExam);

int  inputExam      ( int& Finall);

double OutputQuizz ( int& Q1, int& Q2); // this is meant to calculate the 
                                        // by adding quizz 1 and quizz two to 25%
double  Output ( int& Quizz);            

double OutputMideterm ( int MidExam);

double  OutputExam ( int& Final);

int main()
{

Report FinalGrade ;

int
 x , y ,z  , xz , gr;

   inputQuizzone( x);   
   inputQuizztwo( y);
   inputMideterm(z);
   inputExam( xz);
  cout << " Your Final Grades are " <<  '\n'
 << " Quizzes " << ""   << OutputQuizz( x, y) <<  '\n'
//<< "Quizz Two " << Quizz2<<  '\n'
<< " Mideterm " << OutputMideterm( z) <<  '\n'
<< " Finals " <<   OutputExam(xz)   << endl;




}


int inputQuizzone ( int& Quizz1)
{
cout << " Enter Your Quizz One Score over 10"<< endl;
cin >> Quizz1;

}

 int inputQuizztwo ( int& Quizz2)
{

cout << " Enter Your Second Quizz 2 Score over 10"<< endl;
cin >> Quizz2;

}

int inputMideterm ( int& MidExam)
{

cout << " Enter Your Midterm Score over 100"<< endl;
cin >> MidExam;

}


int inputExam ( int& Finall)
{

cout << " Enter Your Exam Score over 100"<< endl;
cin >> Finall;
return (Finall);

}

double OutputQuizz ( int& Q1, int& Q2)
{

int QR = 0;
QR = (((Q1 + Q2 ) / 20) * 25 ) ;


           return (QR);


}





double OutputMideterm ( int MidExam)

{

int QR = 0;
QR = (MidExam / 100) * 25;
return (QR);
}
double  OutputExam ( int& Final)
{

int QR = 0;
QR = (Final / 100) * 25;

return (QR);
}
```

Comment: If I forget about the messy problem description you copied from somewhere and take your question literally, the answer is: `main()` returns 0 by default unless you `return` something else.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include some example input that causes your problem, and also show the actual *and* expected output? And have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger, line by line? And *what* is "returning 0"?

Comment: Please improve the question by at least stating clearly what function you are talking about that should return something and telling what that something (other than 0) should be.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't so clear, its my first time here. So the program runs but instead of outputting the scores of quizz, midterm and final exam. It gives 0 for all of them. I even tried creating a variable to test if the input  values were actually being passed to  to the different input functions and I found out they were. So I assume the problem is from the ouput functions. I even tried initialing the variables still I get zero for everything when the program runs . please I would like some help on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking at the way values are computed, the main issue is that, in your output functions, you are doing integer arithmetic to compute a value that is smaller than 1. For example, in `OutputQuizz`, `(Q1 + Q2 ) / 20` will usually be less than 1.

To force the compiler to use floating point, use `QR = (((Q1 + Q2 ) / 20.0) * 25.0 )` instead.

You will see values that are not 0.

Comment: Great! You are right. Thank you so much. The program works now